# Working with softlayer instances and images using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am new to this powershell scripting and also to the IBM's softlayer. Can anyone provide me the exact guide for connecting to the softlayer using powershell scripts and working with them like creating devices, starting and stopping e.t.c.

Comment: Use google. There are some useful resources in the first few links. [Voting to close as off-topic (see 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neeli, a good point of start is the following https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Softlayer-API-Overview.

And currently SoftLayer API provides support for [SOAP](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/SOAP)!, [XML-RPC](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/XML-RPC) or [REST](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest) protocols.

Besides SoftLayer API can be used many programming language that support the previous mentioned protocols, please review the following link https://sldn.softlayer.com/ to know more about each one of them and all the information about what IBM SoftLayer API provides.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see an example about how to use powershell and softlayer:

https://softlayer.github.io/tags/powershell/

The example is just performing REST calls to the Softlayer API, so you just need to know how to permor those REST calls.

In documentation you can see how to create a virtual guest or bare metal server using simple Rest calls:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_server/createObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_server/createObject

In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/softlayer you can find many questions about how to use more Softlayer API methods. You just need to know how to do it using REST calls and just write that call to your powershell script.